# How can I have my military advisor executed in Civ V?

Tags: civilization-5

My military advisor gives me such terrible advice that I have come to suspect him of deliberately sabotaging my war effort. Since he's a traitor, where is the button to have him put on trial and executed? Thank you.

Comment: Methinks you've mistaken Civ for a different game.

Comment: I remember the good old days of Civ 2 where the military advisor was a shouting bald man and the entertainment advisor was Elvis.

Answer (score 6):

You can turn off your advisor in Options and choosing Experienced Player to reduce the amount of advice given, or No Advice for no advice at all. I don't believe it is possible to only turn off the military advisor alone.